# How to sort an array of vectors in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector, stdvector

I have created an array of vectors. After taking the input I have to sort them, I guess I need to use a comparator function but I cannot understand how do I use it.

```
int main()
{
    
    int  n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    vector<long long> times[4];
  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        ll t, a, b;
        cin >> t >> a >> b;
        times[a * 2 + b].push_back(t);
    }

    cout << times[0].size();
    ***//i need to sort the whole of times[0] after this***
}
```

Comment: [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is what you want. Take a look and come back when something is unclear.

Comment: vectors already have a `<`, you dont need a custom comparator, unless you want a custom comparison (ie something different than lexicographical order)

Comment: arrray of vectors or vector of arrays. Not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ascending order,

```
sort(times.begin(),times.end());
```

For Descending order,

```
sort(times.begin(), times.end(), greater<int>());
```

Another way,

```
    void cmp(ll a, ll b) { 
      return a < b;  
    }

  // Use the below statement anywhere you want - 
    sort(times.begin(),times.end(),cmp);
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you need to sort.

If you would like to sort the inner array then use sort this way. It sorts times[0]. Second version is with custom comparator

```
std::sort(times[0].begin(), times[0].end());
std::sort(times[0].begin(), times[0].end(), [](ll a, ll b){ return a < b; });
```

if you need to sort "times" array then with your own comparator you can write it this way:

```
std::sort(std::begin(times), std::end(times), 
    [](const std::vector<ll>& a, const std::vector<ll>& b)
    {
        return a.size() < b.size();
    }
);
```

Edit based on comment:

And if lexicographical sorting order is enough then you can skip the custom comparator:

```
std::sort(std::begin(times), std::end(times));
```

Comment: Yes, comparator is no needed if the default lexicographical sorting order is enough. But author didn't mention what kind of order he needs so with this attempt he can adjust it to his own requirements.